# getTag() of TextView on OnTouchEvent in android

Tags: android

I display four `textView` in linear layout. I user `setTag()` of each textView.
When I `ACTION_UP` then `ACTION_MOVE` then `ACTION_UP`.  Event is working fine.  But I `getTag` of `textView` is same. Means view object is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t[] = new TextView[4];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
            t[i] = new TextView(this);
            t[i].setTag(i);
            String s = "Hello :  "+i;
            t[i].setText(s);
            t[i].setTag(i);
            linear.addView(t[i]);
            t[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Log.d("up ", "tag: "+arg0.getTag());
                    } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.d("down ", "tag: "+arg0.getTag());
                    } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        Log.d("move ", "tag: "+arg0.getTag());
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Below is my log.

I `ACTION_DOWN` on `textview0` move to `textview2`. Event is working fine.  But tag of view is not change.  I get same tag on every touch event.  My Log is :

```
11-28 00:55:06.589: D/down(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:06.899: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:06.929: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:07.011: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:07.103: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:07.139: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:07.319: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:07.419: D/move(1980): tag: 0
11-28 00:55:07.522: D/up(1980): tag: 0
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your views final like this:

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++)
    {
        final TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t[i] = t
        t[i].setTag(i);
        String s = "Hello :  "+i;
        t[i].setText(s);
        t[i].setTag(i);
        linear.addView(t[i]);
        t[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {

                if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    Log.d("up ", "tag: "+arg0.getTag());
                }
                else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    Log.d("down ", "tag: "+arg0.getTag());
                }
                else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    Log.d("move ", "tag: "+arg0.getTag());
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it is reolved to textview." I got this error in eclipse at compile time.